# Socket.io room events fires twice

Tags: javascript, mongodb, server, socket.io

The problem is pretty simple,
the room events of socket.io `(eg. "create-room", "join-room", "deleted-room")` fires twice.

```
io.on('connection', async socket => {
   const channel_id = socket.handshake['query']['channel'] as string
   socket.join(channel_id) 
})

io.of('/').adapter.on('create-room', (room) => {
   console.log(`socket has created ${room}`)
})
```

now let's say a room named "demo" was created
the log says :

```
socket has created fa3x6j6Zq7HZiRgYAAAB
socket has created demo
```

mainly trying to do it this way because I want to create a `mongodb` watch stream whenever a room is created and store that in an array, and when a channel is deleted, close that stream by getting it from that array

but since this fires twice, I get two of the same stream adding to that array

how can I stop this? or is it just a bug

Comment: every client connected to the server is put inside a "self" room, this one `fa3x6j6Zq7HZiRgYAAAB` should match the client's ID: `or your convenience, each socket automatically joins a room identified by its own id.` https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/

Comment: @GrafiCode I see, welp no way to achieve the goal then? thank you for your reply regardless!

Comment: you could check if the room ID matches the client ID, and in that case skip the DB insert. this should work on "join-room" event, which gives you as arguments the room object + the socket ID

Comment: @GrafiCode Alright that will probably work, thanks a lot for the answers !

Answer (score 1):

So apparently `each socket automatically joins a room identified by its own id`
Quoted @GrafiCode

I actually didn't notice that it was the socket id, that information is probably enough to solve this by using some conditions